# ASP.net Autopostback dropdown doesnot work for remote url

Tags: asp.net

Update: It looks like happens with IE10. If I have compatibility mode enabled then everything works fine.

I have a master page with a  dropdown definition.  See below

```
    <div style="display: table-cell;"> Customer:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCustomer" runat="server"     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
 </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

And in page init I have following code , updateSelectionlist is just calling database to fillup

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            UpdateSelectionLists();

The above works great when I use localhost to access the site.  When I do a remote public facing url, for some reason there are no events associated to client side dropdown.
below is from viewsource

```
 <select name="ctl00$ddlCustomer" id="ddlCustomer">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Select a customer</option>
    <option value="1">som3</option>
    <option value="7">some2</option>
    <option value="8">some1</option>
    <option value="9">some4</option>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? A bit of code would help too.

Comment: Please show your real code, rather than pseudocode.  And I agree with @MelanciaUK, it would help if you clarified what's wrong.  When you say "there are no events associated to client side drop down", do you mean that the control posts back, but the events don't fire?  Or that it doesn't postback at all?

Comment: i figured the problem, IIS was not identfying the ie10 and hence serving Html page with no JS.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem, IIS was not identfying the ie10 and hence serving Html page with no JS